# MapsCreatorStorageQuotaExceeded error with Azure Maps

Tags: azure-maps

I am using azure-maps API for DWG to GeoJson conversion, where it have started to give below error:

> "400 Bad Request:
> [{"error":{
>
> "code":"MapsCreatorStorageQuotaExceeded",
>
> "message":"Storage
> used by Maps Creator (***.* Mb) exceeds storage available (***.*
> Mb)."}}]"

Although, I have deleting `conversions`, `datasets` and `mapData` resources, but still facing same issue. What else could be consuming the resources here?

Or is there any way, I can check where the storage is being consumed? As I am not the administrator I can't check that in Admin console. I can only access the APIs using api key.

Comment: Linking Q&A post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/737379/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get storage utilization through Creator overview page from Azure Portal.

[image]
[image]

To know more about Creator, see [Manage Azure Maps Creator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-manage-creator?).

Also, Please see the Creator section in [Azure Maps for pricing](https://aka.ms/CreatorPricing) details.

Comment: As I am not admin, I can't see this. I only have the KEY to access APIs. Isn't there any API for that?

Comment: See if it helps: Azure IoT Maps Creator Functional API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps-creator/